# How to find the longest string in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, max

Here is an example array:

```
var friendName = ['RupaKhan','Sunny','Rohul','Mistry','Zumman','Asif','Liza','Fulo'];
```

How do you find the longest name in the array? But you have to use a function with return as well as find as largest name.

I tried this method but it doesn't show a result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43nwC.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Anyway, you have typos in your code.

Comment: You are returning the length instead of name. Try saving name and check `if (largeName.length > friendlist[i].length) largeName=friendlist[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var friendName = ['RupaKhan','Sunny','Rohul','Mistry','Zumman','Asif','Liza','Fulo'];

function mega(arr){
   return arr.reduce((max,name)=>{
        return name.length > max.length? name: max
    },arr[0])
}

console.log(mega(friendName))
```